# 12.04 - sound is laggy when running games through Wine

Tags: 12.04, sound, wine

Lenovo U400
Wine 1.5.5
Ubuntu 12.04 with all updates applied

I'm experiencing severe (~500ms) audio lag in all games run in Wine.  Portal 2, Half-Life, World of Goo, and Fallout are all exhibiting this problem.  When I run winecfg though and click the "Test Sound" button at the bottom of the Audio tab, the sound effect appears to play immediately.  So I'm not sure what's going on.  I don't think it's a problem with PulseAudio by itself since totem videos and Youtube clips both play in perfect sync.

Anyone have any ideas on where to start fixing this?  thanks!

(edit: I thought this was limited to Steam games but I installed a non-Steam game and I now see that's not the case.  I get audio lag in other apps too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled PulseAudio by setting the environment variable WINENOPULSE=1 and Wine apps seem to work fine now.